# sql/plsql - insert rows from source table to target with one column in target depending on another column in Source table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a requirement where I have to insert rows (a few hundred rows) from one table (say source) to another (say target). But there is a column in target (say Error column) whose value for every row depends on a column (say Email) in source. 
For example, if source.email is null then target.error = 'no email'(hardcoded) else target.error = others (hardcoded). All other columns that are to be populated in target table are present in the source table. What is the efficient way of inserting the rows?

Comment: `select AllYourColumns, case when source.email==null then target.error='no email'(hardcoded) else target.error = others.(hardcoded) end from YourTable`

Comment: Sample data and expected results would help. Sounds like you need a [`CASE` expression](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/expressions004.htm).

Comment: Why do you think you need a stored procedure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
1. insert into target select col1,col2, decode(email,null,'no 
   email','others') col4, col5 from source;

2  insert into target select col1,col2, case when email is null then 'no 
   email' else 'others' end col4 , col5 
    from source.
```

1  The Decode- Function works like a if else –Clause

```
   decode(email,null,'no  email','others')
```

can be written like

```
 if email is null then 'no  email' else 'others' end if
```

[see hier](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions040.htm)

2.The Case when clause is similar/ same to the If else clause

The

```
 insert into select
```

statement copies the data from source and inserts it into the target, when data types in source and target matches.

```
 Insert into target(col1,col2) select col1, col2 from source
```

can be written like

```
   Insert into targert select col,col2 from source
```

When the target only contains the two columns

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/350567) by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.